# Guice creation errors: Cloudify

Tags: glassfish, guice, netbeans-7, jclouds, cloudify

I'm new to Guice and indeed cloudify and I hoping to get a pointer or areas to look at as to what may be causing this:

1. Firstly :

   ```
   No implementation for com.google.common.cache.LoadingCache<org.jclouds.ec2.domain.RunningInstance, org.jclouds.domain.LoginCredentials> was bound.
     while locating com.google.common.cache.LoadingCache<org.jclouds.ec2.domain.RunningInstance, org.jclouds.domain.LoginCredentials>
       for parameter 9 at org.jclouds.aws.ec2.compute.strategy.AWSEC2CreateNodesInGroupThenAddToSet.<init>(AWSEC2CreateNodesInGroupThenAddToSet.java:94)
     at org.jclouds.aws.ec2.compute.config.AWSEC2ComputeServiceContextModule.configure(AWSEC2ComputeServiceContextModule.java:96)
   ```
2. And :

   ```
   No implementation for com.google.common.cache.CacheLoader<org.jclouds.ec2.domain.RunningInstance, org.jclouds.domain.Credentials> was bound.
     at org.jclouds.ec2.compute.config.EC2ComputeServiceDependenciesModule.credentialsMap(EC2ComputeServiceDependenciesModule.java:169)
   2 errors
   ```

The code for `1` is :-

```
public class AWSEC2ComputeServiceContextModule extends BaseComputeServiceContextModule {
@Override
protected void configure() {
super.configure();
    installDependencies();
    install(new EC2BindComputeStrategiesByClass());
    install(new AWSEC2BindComputeSuppliersByClass());
    bind(ReviseParsedImage.class).to(AWSEC2ReviseParsedImage.class);
    bind(CreateKeyPairAndSecurityGroupsAsNeededAndReturnRunOptions.class).to(
           CreateKeyPairPlacementAndSecurityGroupsAsNeededAndReturnRunOptions.class);
    bind(EC2HardwareSupplier.class).to(AWSEC2HardwareSupplier.class);
    bind(EC2TemplateBuilderImpl.class).to(AWSEC2TemplateBuilderImpl.class);
    bind(EC2GetNodeMetadataStrategy.class).to(AWSEC2GetNodeMetadataStrategy.class);
    bind(EC2ListNodesStrategy.class).to(AWSEC2ListNodesStrategy.class);
    bind(EC2DestroyNodeStrategy.class).to(AWSEC2DestroyNodeStrategy.class);
    bind(InstancePresent.class).to(AWSEC2InstancePresent.class);
    bind(EC2CreateNodesInGroupThenAddToSet.class).to(AWSEC2CreateNodesInGroupThenAddToSet.class);
    bind(RunningInstanceToNodeMetadata.class).to(AWSRunningInstanceToNodeMetadata.class);
}
```

The code for `2` is :-

```
@Provides
@Singleton
@Named("SECURITY")
protected LoadingCache<RegionAndName, String> securityGroupMap(
        @Named("SECURITY") CacheLoader<RegionAndName, String> in) {
    return CacheBuilder.newBuilder().build(in);
}
```

My initial thoughts are it could be a jar file missing or missing items in the path?  Any pointers and guidance is appreciated.  This is on `Netbeans 7.3 beta`, `Java 1.7`, `GlassFish`, `Cloudify 2.5.0-SNAPSHOT`, Windows 7 Professional 64 bit on a Bootcamped IMAC.

Comment: When are you getting these errors? Running the Cloudify CLI? Which commands? You mention Netbeans, are you trying to run Cloudify in a debugger?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some jar files from your classpath. At the very least you should have the jar files in the following directories in your classpath:

- CLOUDIFY_HOME/lib/required/*
- CLOUDIFY_HOME/lib/platform/esm/*
- CLOUDIFY_HOME/lib/platform/cloudify/*

Answer (score 0):

Also check the Java version you're using. if it's 1.7u51 or higher, it doesn't work well with the jclouds version used by cloudify, and specifically with Guice (issue described [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JCLOUDS-427)).

Reverting to an earlier JDK (1.7u45 or lower) should resolve it.